# Does Marketplaces use many-to-many association in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was looking at this site called codementor.io, and i was wondering if that is considered using a many-to-many association?

(beginner Rails guy here)

Comment: Please improve you question if you want a meaningful answer. Are you asking if the association between mentors and mentees is coded on a many-to-many relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell about any particular resource, but many to many relation is very popular. It IS used both as has_and_belongs_to_many(habtm) and as `has_many :through` The difference is when you use habtm you don't need to create model for joined table(only table in database).
Find out more at  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html